# Boost #include is failing on XCode even though boost is on the header search path

Tags: c++, xcode, boost

I have a copy of boost installed at `/usr/local/ogre/ogre1.8/iOSDependencies/include`:

[image]

...

[image]

In XCode, a cpp file is failing to compile because a file it includes has a line:

`#include <boost/thread/tss.hpp>`

The XCode compile cmdline to CompileC includes

`-I/usr/local/ogre/ogre1.8/iOSDependencies/include`

Everything looks just fine to me... `<boost/...>` is a child of `/usr/local/ogre/ogre1.8/iOSDependencies/include` and thread/tss.hpp clearly exists. Why would XCode think otherwise? I tried a clean build without any success.

The XCode project settings look like this:

[image]

> `fatal error: 'boost/thread/tss.hpp' file not found`
>   `#include <boost/thread/tss.hpp>`

Comment: Is that path also in the C++ include path?

Comment: It's in the XCode "Header Search Paths" - works for everything else!

Comment: What happens if you provide full path in #include line? Does it work with another thread/*.h files?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but could it possibly be file permissions?  If you logged in and installed boost as root from the command-line (or something similar) it is possible that xcode cannot read that directory path or some directory leading up to it.

Comment: @AlexFarber it's a 3rd-party lib but I can hack it to test that.

Comment: @JohnBowers the file which is doing the `#include <>` is part of a  separate library which _is_ building just fine. e.g project A includes the boost files and builds fine, then project B has a dependency on A and is the one that fails when it include's A's headers.

Comment: You do have the header search path for boost in *both* projects right?

Comment: I added additional screenshot of project settings

Comment: As @abellina says you need to set that header search path for both Xcode targets, not just the Xcode target for "A". Note that it may be possible to refactor the headers "A" so that this isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

" First, you must have compiled boost on iPhone using the code and instructions from the boostoniphone project.

Navigate within the "boostoniphone" folder to the "framework" folder. Click on the "boost.framework" folder in that location, and drag it into the main xcode window, in the left hand side column, into the "frameworks" group (along with all the other frameworks, i.e. Foundation.framework, UIKit.framework, etc.)

That's it. If you added any build settings while trying to get this to work,remove them."

The above is the answer I found after some research. Please comment on my answer if it did help you solve your issue.

Comment: It might fix it but it's not really the solution I'm after... I have a pre-built boost as part of the 3rd-party libs so I don't want to build a separate framework to what they provide.